dual focus on form elements and icons with voice over turned on
While my CSS styles successfully apply a focus border to form elements, this behavior is inconsistent when VoiceOver is enabled. VoiceOver appears to create its own additional border on top of the element's default focus border, resulting in a visually distracting with a "dual focus" effect. Looks like When VoiceOver is activated, a black border appears in addition to the component's default border. This issue seems to be more prevalent with form elements but can potentially occur across other components as well.
VoiceOver OFF:

VoiceOver ON:

This dual focus issue with VoiceOver is a significant accessibility concern and requires prioritization. Are there any settings within VoiceOver utility that might mitigate this problem?  Alternatively, are there known workarounds or best practices to ensure our components display a single, clear focus indicator when VoiceOver is active?
Expecting to have only a single focus with Voice over turned On


why is this a significant accessibility concern? Having a border on the active element is an accessibility feature of VoiceOver. This is not an issue as the dual border effect is primarily due to accessibility features provided by two separate apps - your app and VoiceOver. If you really need to fix it, you may have to adjust your app code's hover focus border to match/merge with the VoiceOver border, as you cannot control VoiceOver, you can only control your code.

"This dual focus issue with VoiceOver is a significant accessibility concern" Why?
